# I can't validate the response body using cy.intercept in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

After editing a field in the frontend and saving the edit, I did a cy.intercept in a GET to capture the response and check if the "maximum_quantity" attribute was updated to the value 30.
But I can't navigate through the response to the "maximum_quantity" attribute to check if the value 30 is there. Below is my code and the error message.

CODE:

```
cy.intercept('GET', '***/all-offerings?page=0&size=15&not_status=deactivated',).as('max')

cy.wait('@max')
  .its("response.statusCode")
  .should("eq", 200)

cy.get('@max')
  .then(res => {
    expect(res.data[0].items[0].maximum_quantity).to.have.value(30)
})
```

Error message

[image]

Json response

[image]

Comment: Doesn't `cy.get()` only query the DOM? See https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Waiting-on-a-request

Comment: I used cy.wait() and received the error message below:
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but object given

Comment: You probably want `res.body.data[0].items[0]` if neither `res.body.items[0]` nor `res.data[0].items[0]` are working.

Comment: But why the guessing games? What is `res` when you console.log it?

Comment: The reason is `res` is not res - it's an `interception` which means you want `.then(interception => { expect(interception.response.data[0]` or same but with `interception.response.body.data[0]`.

Comment: As already mentioned, just log what you get back - not difficult to solve.

Answer (score 3):

From the screenshots of the response, your code should include the `data` array as part of the path you test.

```js
cy.get('@max')
  .then(res => {
    expect(res.body.data[0].items[0].maximum_quantity).to.have.value(30)
  })
```

although maybe there is no `body` in the path since the error says can't read items of *undefined*, which would mean `body` is the undefined part.

If so use this

```js
cy.get('@max')
  .then(res => {
    expect(res.data[0].items[0].maximum_quantity).to.have.value(30)
  })
```

Comment: I ran the tests both ways and both showed an error.

Comment: In the first case the error appeared:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Comment: In the second case the error appears:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: The "second case" means you have not given the correct details of the response. Please update the question.

Comment: @Jackson.J.Lamb I updated the question.